# How to interpret numpy advanced indexing solution

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-indexing, advanced-indexing

I have a piece of numpy code that **I know works**. I know this because I have tested it in my generic case successfully. However, I arrived at the solution after two hours of back and forth referencing the docs and trial and error. I can't grasp how I would know to do this *intuitively*.

The setup:

```
a = np.zeros((5,5,3))
```

The goal: Set to 1 indices 0,1 of axis 1,  0,1 of axis 2, all of axis 3 and indices 3,4 of axis 1, 3,4 of axis 2, all of axis 3

**Clearer goal: Set block 1 and 2's first two rows to 1 and block 3 and 4's last two rows to 1**

The result:

```
ax1 =np.array([np.array([0,1]),np.array([3,4])])
ax1 =np.array([x[:,np.newaxis] for x in ax1])
ax2 = np.array([[[0,1]],[[3,4]]])
a[ax1,ax2,:] = 1
a
```

Output:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]],

   [[1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.]],

   [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

I'm inclined to believe I should be able to look at the shape of the matrix in question, the shape of the indices, and the index operation to intuitively know the output. However, I can't put the story together in my head. Like, what's the final shape of the subspace it is altering? **How would you explain how this works?**

The shapes:

```
input: (5, 5, 3)
ind1: (2, 2, 1)
ind2: (2, 1, 2)
final_op: input[ind1, ind2, :]
```

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? As in, more quantitative?

Comment: I think I can now clarify the question for posterity, since reading @hpaulij's answer makes everything clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With shapes

```
ind1: (2, 2, 1)
ind2: (2, 1, 2)
```

they `broadcast` together to select a (2,2,2) space

```
In [4]: ax1
Out[4]: 
array([[[0],
        [1]],

       [[3],
        [4]]])
In [5]: ax2
Out[5]: 
array([[[0, 1]],

       [[3, 4]]])
```

So for the 1st dimension (blocks) it is selecting blocks 0,1,3,and 4.  In the second dimension it is also selecting these rows.

Together that's the first 2 rows of the first 2 blocks, and the last 2 rows of the last 2 blocks.  That's where the 1s appear in your result.

A simpler way of creating the index arrays:

```
In [7]: np.array([[0,1],[3,4]])[:,:,None]   # (2,2) expanded to (2,2,1)
In [8]: np.array([[0,1],[3,4]])[:,None,:]   # expand to (2,1,2)
```

This is how broadcasting expands them:

```
In [10]: np.broadcast_arrays(ax1,ax2)
Out[10]: 
[array([[[0, 0],              # block indices
         [1, 1]],
 
        [[3, 3],
         [4, 4]]]),
 array([[[0, 1],              # row indices
         [0, 1]],
 
        [[3, 4],
         [3, 4]]])]
```

This may make the pattern clearer:

```
In [15]: a[ax1,ax2,:] = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2,1)
In [16]: a[:,:,0]
Out[16]: 
array([[1., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 4., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 4.]])
```

Comment: Thank you, your thorough explanation and steps in between really helped drill home the concept.